# Apt-get unavailable

Tags: 15.04

I've got an issue with apt-get, I can not use it. i've got this message:

```
apt-get: symbol lookup error: apt-get: undefined symbol: _ZN13pkgSrcRecords6Parser6Files2ERSt6vectorINS_5File2ESaIS2_EE
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Please post the whole command.